# Replacement for Collection.getElementNodeName(); in Hibernate 5.4.27

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to migrate Hibernate from 3.6 to 5.4.27 and I am unable to find the below method in 5.4.27

```
org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.getElementNodeName();

for (Collection col : getCollections())
    {
        String referencedEntity = col.getElementNodeName();
        Value val = col.getElement();

        if (val instanceof ToOne)
        {
            ToOne to = (ToOne) val;
            referencedEntity = to.getReferencedEntityName();

        }

      // some logic with the referencedEntity value..
    }
```

I tried to read through older java doc's to find more info on what this method returns to understand its suitable replacement but was unable to find any documentation.

Any idea on what this method returns and what would be possible replacement?

Comment: Could you please show how you use this method.

Comment: @SternK have updated the usage

Comment: Please also show how you then use `referencedEntity`. Do you pass this to some other hibernate api method?

Comment: And one more question: Do you use mapping with annotation or xml files approach ?

Comment: @SternK using mapping xml files

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the old code, it was returning the FQN of the element entity type. You should be able to use `((ToOne) col.getElement()).getReferencedEntityName()` to achieve the same.

Comment: @Chrishtian Beikov thanks for the response yes I am currently using the above line of code if its an instance of ToOne but the question is what to do when its not an instance of ToOne ?

Comment: Have updated the code snippet with the usage

Comment: Nothing, in that case you'd have an element collection for which there is no entity.